# In Mac OSX, Weka does not recognize Python (Possible Python Conflict)

Tags: python, macos, path, anaconda, weka

In Mac OSX, I installed [Anaconda3](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos) to be the default python interpreter. When I run [Weka](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), the following messages appear in the log:

```
19:56:28: Started on Friday, 4 May 2018
19:56:29: Python is not available!!
19:56:29: Library "sklearn" is not available
Library "pandas" is not available, minimum version = 0.7.0
```

It seems there is a conflict here because `whereis python` gives me `/usr/bin/python` while `which python` gives me `/anaconda3/bin/python`. If I want o keep `Anaconda3` as the default Python interpreter, how can allow Weka to find sklearn exists in `Anaconda3`, or at least how can I install sklearn in `/usr/bin/python`?

PS: When I try to install `sklearn` using `pip install -U scikit-learn` hoping that it gets installed in `/usr/bin/python` I get `Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.19.1)`

Thank you

Comment: So first of all can you type in the terminal `which python` and tell us the result?

Comment: @HarisNadeem It is `/anaconda3/bin/python`.

Comment: cool, can you know type `pip freeze` and let me know if weka is listed?

Comment: @HarisNadeem Not in the list !!!

Comment: It's just as I thought

Comment: Now do another thing for me.... type `/usr/bin/python -m pip freeze` and let me know what you see

Comment: @HarisNadeem Thank you for your help. I got `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`

Comment: Very interesting. I have worked with Weka in java and anconda in python but never Weka in python. However, the issue you are facing is having multiple python versions. If you type `whereis python` you will see that you have a python in `/usr/bin/python` and `/anaconda3/bin/python`

Comment: Could you share details with how you installed weka python on your Mac so that I may correct your mistake and that way I don't have to write a full blown tutorial? :)

Comment: Yes Sure I will update my post

Comment: Ok, wait... you want to use sklearn not weka yes?

Comment: also could you list how you are launching the program? Because the thing is you have sklearn and pandas installed if you type `conda list`. The only thing is to configure them to work correctly and not have the two python versions clash

Comment: I want to use Weka. And yes, `conda list` shows both sklearn and pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PRE-REQUISITES**

So the first thing you may want to do is figure out which default python you have by typing `/usr/bin/python -V`

By default Mac OS X has python 2.7 installed and so I will continue the tutorial with that in mind. If you want to install python 3, you may do so first and then follow the rest of the tutorial making changes for python2 with python3

**INTRO**

Ok so there is a small problem that I found. Apparently, I could not find a way to configure weka with Anaconda, however there is an easy way to configure Python with Weka. The only issue would be to setting up your python instance.

**Step 1: Installing PIP**

The first thing you need to do is install python's officially-sanctioned package manager called *PIP*. Installing it on Mac OS X is different from Linux distributions like Ubuntu and can be followed [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) (Remember when you typed `/usr/bin/python pip freeze`? It complained that you don't have pip and you need it).

Pip will be used to install libraries such as pandas, sklearn and the python weka wrapper.

**STEP 2**

This next step is usually optional, but since you have anaconda installed, this would be mandatory for you.

You want to install a virtual environment where python2.7 is your default python interpreter.

you would want to run:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper --user
mkdir <new_work_directory>
cd <new_work_directory>
/usr/bin/python -m mkvirtualenv <environment name>
/usr/bin/python -m workon <environment name>
```

**STEP 4**

Check and make sure your default python is correctly configured:

```
which python
pip install pandas sklearn python-weka-wrapper3 --user
```

And voila you should be good!

To exit your virtual env type: `deactivate`. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Let me know if there are any issues

Comment: Thank you so much. Very well explained and fix it correctly

Comment: Glad to be of help  :) 
And extremely happy that the instructions were perfectly instructed, especially since I don't have a Mac :D
Funny enough, I saw you because of the weka tag, although this was more of an anaconda issue lol.